# Why is there no compile error since the method only returns in the "if" block?

Tags: oop, flutter, dart

I am working with Dart in Flutter right now, and in a tutorial I came across this method:

```
Future getData() async {
http.Response response = await http.get(url);

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  String data = response.body;
  return jsonDecode(data);
} else {
  print(response.statusCode);
}
}
```

Why is there no compile error? In Java or C++, there would be an error because if statusCode wasn't 200, the method wouldn't return anything. Is it because Future can act like a void type? Just don't really understand what is going on.

Comment: If you run `dartanalyzer` on your code, you should get a static analysis error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,

When you define a "Future" it automatically defaults to

```
Future<void> or Future<dynamic>
```

If you want to force it to a certain return type you must declare it like so.

```
Future<int> or Future<double>
```

You get the idea.

However Dart doesn't operate like Java or C++, if you create a function that is supposed to return a value, but in a certain if, else clause there is no return clause, then the function will return null.